# Can I get sued for using a betting bot?

Tags: software, gambling, robot

I have created a bot for roulette that makes a bet on a certain condition.

In their terms of service, the casino — PokerStars Casino — says that any use of bots is prohibited. I understand that I can get banned for this, but can I get sued for using such a bot?

My bot does not use any code inside PokerStars software. Instead, it works by checking colors on the screen and automatically pressing on the screen.

Also, I understand that casinos are built such that the house always wins and I am only doing this for fun.

Comment: How would PokerStars know you're using a bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The casino (PokerStars Casino) in their terms of service says that any
>   use of bots is prohibited.

That's all you need to know.

It doesn't matter how your bot works, if you don't intend to make money, if it doesn't use any code of PokerStars, if it is only for fun, or any of your reasons. You're breaking the TOS and open yourself to civil action by the company; if not criminal action by a prosecutor in their chosen legal jurisdiction and/or a prosecutor in your own jurisdiction.

Comment: Ok I will stop using it then :). Thank you

Comment: In reality, there's virtually no chance of criminal action if it's  not for profit, and it's likely damages would be limited to your profit or the casino's loss (ie 0). The casino might still take action, though, *pour encourager les autres*.